# Using Grep to search for multiple words in a file

Tags: bash, grep

I want to use `grep` in an If statement to search for a first-name and last-name within a text file.  I can't seem to make it work on my own.

```
if [[ grep -E "$first|$last" Datafile.txt ]]
    then
            echo "This name already exists"
    else
            echo "This name doesn't exist yet"
    fi
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `[[` operator, just:

```
if grep -qwE "${first}|${last}" Datafile.txt; then
  echo "This name already exists"
else
  echo "This name doesn't exist yet"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

more simpler way. make a new file that will contain your search key-word, one per line.

```
grep --file=<filename containing search keys> <filename to find into>
```